# Laravel/Lumen MemcachedStore calculateExpiration method (memcached set with unixtimestamp)

Tags: php, memcached

In core I have aforementioned class (MemcachedStore), which has put method as:

```
        $a = $this->memcached->set(
            $this->prefix.$key, $value, $this->calculateExpiration($seconds)
        );
```

Memcached's [set](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/memcached.set.php) method accepts three parameters: key, value, seconds_to_store_in_cache

My questions is: Why would I need to calculate expiration Carbon::now() + seconds passed to this function?

Result: This is not working. Memcached returns 0 "success". But entry is not written. (With "get" method I cant find it)

If I just pass seconds (override in core class), everything works as expected

UPD! Nothing to do with laravel or lumen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Memchached's `set` method can accept [third parameter as unixtimestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/memcached.expiration.php), but in this case memcached time (os time) should be correct. Memcached time can be checked by Memchached's `getStats`